# Nginx location directive doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something?

Tags: nginx

I've set up Nginx as my main web server and have two Mochiweb based servers behind it. Certain requests are reverse-proxied to these two servers. 
now, I want to access phpmyadmin (located at /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin) using nginx, but it keeps saying Error 404 not found. Am I missing something obvious here?

```
server {
    ############### General Settings ####################
    listen   80;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log  /home/me/dev/wwwaccess.log;

    ############## Document Root #######################    
    location / {
        root   /home/me/dev;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    ############## PHPMyAdmin #######################   
    location /phpmyadmin {
        root   /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

    ############## Proxy Settings for FastCGI Server #####
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /home/me/dev$fastcgi_script_name;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }


    ############# Proxy Settings for Mochi1 ###############
    location /mochi1 {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         3600;

            proxy_buffering off;
        }

    ############# Proxy Settings for Mochi2 ###############
    location /mochi2 {
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001;
            proxy_redirect     off;

            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

            client_max_body_size       10m;
            client_body_buffer_size    128k;

            proxy_connect_timeout      90;
            proxy_send_timeout         90;
            proxy_read_timeout         3600;

            proxy_buffering off;
        }

    ############# Error redirection pages ################
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /home/me/dev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The problem here is that only the "best" `location` directive gets taken, in this order:

```
location =  <path>  (longest match wins)
location ^~ <path>  (longest match wins)
location ~  <path>  (first defined match wins)
location    <path>  (longest match wins)
```

Using this ruleset, your `/phpmyadmin` `location` directive is beaten out by the regular expression "`.php$`" `location` directive, so the former is ignored entirely. Additionally, your php fastcgi directive is hard-wired to your `/home/me/dev` directory, which means that phpMyAdmin is totally inaccessible. You can use a rewrite to get the correct root for your phpMyAdmin scripts:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    set $php_root /home/me/dev;
    if ($request_uri ~* /phpmyadmin) {
        set $php_root /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin;
    }

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried this a long time back but it never worked back then. I always got HTTP 404 errors. Only now I figured out the problem. I had the phpmyadmin files under /var/www/nginx-default/phpmyadmin. When nginx processes the directive for a php file, it searches inside /var/www/nginx-default/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin the second phpmyadmin being the one from the request. That is from the root directory, it searches for the relative directory which is again phpmyadmin. So I had to create another directory inside phpmyadmin and put all the files there. Now it works!

Comment: +1 I just burned up the last 2 hours trying to figure out the issue with my nginx.conf and FINALLY ended up here... I'm new to nginx and it's very frustrating to get things just right...

Comment: Great answer. I did not realize that Nginx always chooses only one location, even if more than one matches. I have to admit that it was clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the `if` directive? The Nginx docs  say to avoid `if` when possible (although perhaps there's no other good way in this case).

Comment: This answer does not set all the right params - for example its not setting the 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' param correctly. See my answer below for details.

Comment: Isn't wrong to say that for `location =` the "longest match wins"? If the matching is exact, there can be only one match.

Comment: @user558061, I have two location i.e. location / {} and location /backend/. In that my backend location is not running. What will be the issue?

Comment: Marcus Griep: You are the best, sir! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Set the 'root' directly.  Less directives, less computing needed to set more vars.  There are also other things (like fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT) that will not be set correctly in the currently accepted answer.  This method will handle all that however:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    if ($request_uri ~* /phpmyadmin) {
        root /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin;
    }

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: if `/phpmyadmin` is part of the URI (`http://host:port/phpmyadmin/...`), root should be set to `/var/www/nginx-default/`, unless phpmyadmin is installed to `/var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin/phpmyadmin`.

Comment: This answer helped me very much, thanks a lot)
I should mention that there should be ';' at the end of this line:
root /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for hours now and none of the solutions discussed above worked to my case (since i needed to run index.php, index.php with arguments, and other php scripts than index.php), but finally reached the working configurations as the following:

```
    location /php-app {
    passenger_enabled off;
    alias /path/to/php-app/$1;
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
   }

   location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/php-app(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
   }

location ~ \.php$ {
    alias /path/to/php-app/$1;
    rewrite ^/php-app(.*)$ $1 last;
    passenger_enabled off;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/php-app$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it searches for index.html? Try changing to

```
location /phpmyadmin {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default/phpMyAdmin;
    index index.php;
}
```

and add section below, to avoid case-related issues

```
location /phpMyAdmin {
   rewrite ^/* /phpmyadmin last;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a practical example of a configuration to serve two diferent folders, one protected and other not protected.

Nginx is serving two folders:
/usr/share/nginx/html/  at  http:yourhost:port/  (protected with htpasswd)
/usr/share/nginx/static/  at  http:yourhost:port/health/  (open to allow heath monitoring)

```html
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ^~ /health/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/static;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```