# Serving php files from different locations in nginx

Tags: php, configuration, nginx

I have my main website and wordpress in different directories on my server on which I use nginx as the web server. The main website is in /home/me/www and Wordpress is in /home/me/wordpress. I need to have them in separate directories this way for a particular reason. How do I specify this in the nginx configuration file? I currently have the following and it does not work:

```
location / {
    root   /home/me/www;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location /blog {
    root /home/me/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    set $php_root /home/me/www;
    if ($request_uri ~ /blog) {
        set $php_root /home/me/wordpress;
    }
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

It currently returns HTTP 404 when I try to access http://mydomain/blog

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011101/nginx-location-directive-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-am-i-missing-something) and the [Nginx Manual](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpCoreModule#location).

Try changing your `blog` line to:

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    root /home/me/wordpress;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually, the question that you have pointed to is one that I had asked a long time back! I never got it to work based on the answer. Only today I got it to work. I've posted a comment on that answer.

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with this for hours now and finally reached the working configurations as the following:

```
location /php-app {
    passenger_enabled off;
    alias /path/to/php-app/$1;
    index index.php index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/php-app(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    alias /path/to/php-app/$1;
    rewrite ^/php-app(.*)$ $1 last;
    passenger_enabled off;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.socket;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/php-app$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```