# PHP not working within a location directive

Tags: php, nginx

I've set up a test Virtualbox/Debian Wheezy7.1 machine with a bare net-install machine + nginx + php-fpm

I've got SSL, php , basic_auth  and allow/deny to work on a server level.

However, If i want the auth stuff to be for one path only, the auth works, but the PHP stuff does not (the index.php gets downloaded in the web browser)

I know it has something to do with how nginx matches location directives, but i'm not sure what it is...

Here is my config file:

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.test.com;
       rewrite        ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}



# HTTPS server

server
{
    listen 443;
    server_name www.test.com;

    root /srv/vhosts/www.test.com/html;
    index index.php ;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/STAR.test.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/STAR.test.com.key;

    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                # With php5-fpm:
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }   

    location ^~ /testdir/ {
        auth_basic "gib login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd/www.test.com.htpasswd;
        allow 192.168.1.3;   # my workstation ip
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Edit: Look at first comment, thanks!

Comment: I've managed to solve my issue by changing this: 'location ^~ /testdir/' to this 'location /testdir/'. I still don't know why this works, and would appreciate if someone would elaborate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html), the order of location directives matters.

> To determine which location directive matches a particular query, the
>   literal strings are checked first. Literal strings match the beginning
>   portion of the query - the most specific match will be used.
>   Afterwards, regular expressions are checked in the order defined in
>   the configuration file. The first regular expression to match the
>   query will stop the search. If no regular expression matches are
>   found, the result from the literal string search is used.

Try organizing your location directives so that the directory you want to protect comes first, followed by PHP, followed by your `try__files` directive. I did a quick test on my system and structuring the location blocks in the following order allowed `testdir` to be protected and for `index.php` to still be executed.

```
location ^~ /testdir/ {
    auth_basic "gib login";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/htpasswd/www.test.com.htpasswd;
    allow 192.168.1.3;   # my workstation ip
    deny all;
}

location ~ \.php$ {

}

location ~ / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ 404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you take a look at the comment in the question comment section? Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the documentation link I provided. Nginx processes location blocks in a specific order. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011101/nginx-location-directive-doesnt-seem-to-be-working-am-i-missing-something/1099252#1099252) provides some more insight into that.