# Nginx configuration for a sudirectory with PHP is returning 404

Tags: php, apache, nginx

I have a website www.example.com using a custom PHP framework and a CMS that loads a completely different framework. It was initially on apache2 and now I am trying to move to nginx. The www domain loads file but when it comes to loading the codebase in the subdirectory, it is simply returning 404 on my nginx. If I switch back to apache2, it loads fine. Here is my config which I basically cobbled from looking at other stackoverflow answers:

```
server {
listen 80 default;
client_max_body_size 256M;
access_log /var/log/nginx/site.access.log;

root /site;
index index.php;

if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/site_php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location /cms {
    root /cms/;
}

location ~ /cms/.+\.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/site_php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1099252/2165516) but did not have much luck. I must have some basic configuration incorrectly setup but can't seem to figure out which. The .htaccess in the /cms is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /cms

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**Edit**: Updated the config using [this example](https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory) and I now can login to the CMS but it immediately goes into a 302 redirect loop which I can't figure out why it is happening:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;

# client_max_body_size 256M;

root /application;

index index.php;

server_name _;

# access_log /var/log/nginx/application.access.log;

location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

location /cms {
        alias /application/cms;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cms;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        }
    }

location @cms {
    rewrite /cms/(.*)$ /cms/index.php?/$1 last;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
}
```

}

Comment: stupid but important question, all your `root` refer to valid and existing path ?

Comment: @Yanis-git Yep it does. Works perfectly fine with apache2 which I presume would be an issue if it was a path issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i have find your issue, on your actual code, this part : `location ~ \.php$ {`
expect to find file call `.php` is why you always have 404 error. Just update like this :

```
location ~ index.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "error_log=/var/log/nginx/application_php_errors.log";
    fastcgi_buffers 32 32k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 64k;
}
```

I recommand you to use : `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;` (please check available socket on `/run/php/`folder) instead of local network call `php-fpm:9000`. Is much performing.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed it and I eventually got it working with just ```~ \.php$``` as well after finding out a PHP issue. And the reason for php-fpm:9000 is I am using it a standard nginx/php-fpm Docker. I will have a look if it is possible to do it in the container. In the server I use what you recommended. Thanks.

Comment: oh unfortunately you can't do it by socket with docker. Forget this optimization so

Answer (score 0):

Add this derective just after the line index index.php

```
location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args; 
}
```

Regards

Comment: Updated the answer with the changes I made but now it is creating a 302 redirect loop!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that NGINX web servers do not read `.htaccess`.
So it must be that the `.htacces` you have provided is not being read at all.

You can try to convert it to NGINX counterpart.
see the accepted answer in this stackoverflow question. It might help you

[Change Apache .htaccess file to be used with Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8711678/change-apache-htaccess-file-to-be-used-with-nginx)

Comment: I am aware of .htaccess not working on nginx. Tried those tools to no avail as well! And unfortunately the answer did not help either.